# CKEditor doesnt want appear if it already in cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ckeditor

I am trying to setup CKEditor (https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) it seems to be very simple, and its work fine on first page load, but if I go back(to the root or elsewhere on same browser page) and then again go to edit or new form I`ve just get simple text area field, so when I open it in new window everything is fine.

I think that the problem is in rails or browser cache... So I have to do somthing to prevent this page from caching or to clear cache after action... but I cant understand how to implement this. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, solved, if it help somebody:
Just put

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function(){
              $(".ckeditor").ckeditor();
              };
        </script>`
```

at the bottom of the page, just before body closing tag.